# How to write raw JavaScript code to file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, fs

Assume that in `index.js` we have the code

```
class TestClass {
   testMethod() {
      console.log('OK');
   }
}
```

We want to write this modified code to `output.js`, for example:

```
export default class TestClass {
   testMethod() {
      console.log('OK');
   }
}
```

Everybody of novices in Node.js can output some text contents with `fs.writeFile`. The subject in this question is which features are required when we want to generate JavaScript file from other JavaScript file. I suppose, before using `fs`, we need to preprocess the target JavaScript code. Is it enough to just stringify in, id if so, how to do it? Id Node.js provides some tools for this?

Comment: What's the specific reason for this?  There is very rarely a case where you should need to modify code with code.

Comment: What you want is grasp.js or the like via which you can do AST rewriting.

Comment: @Brad, for example, when we need to generate TypeScript type definitions based on JSON/YAML data.